# Windows 11 graftabl command isn't there anymore?

Tags: windows, dos

I just noticed this today on win 11 pro. The graftabl command gives a "'graftabl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

It's still mentioned when you HELP at the command prompt though....

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/graftabl